# Is a web crawler what I need? Or maybe a web scraper?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to automate this process:
- login into a web site
- navigate to a page
- retrieve a piece of information

This should happen into a Java program. I know there are some open source Java libraries (JSpider, crawler4j and others) but I cannot understand if they fit my needs.

I a spider/crawler what I need? If not, what do I need, and does it exist ever?

Comment: No, you don't want or need a web crawler for this. You need to code each step yourself: Make login (POST) request, make another GET request for the page you want, parse the response and extract the information.

Comment: I don't like this answer! :) I always like to do the coding by myself, but this time I wanted to see if something similar already existed...

Comment: Your requirement is very specific. For example, login on one web application is different than a logic on another web application.

Comment: Yes, but it's surprising that nobody yet tought of implementing such a framework. To be clearer, I'll explain my real need: I would like to login on the site of my mobile phone operator, navigate to the residual credit page and then grab the value. In a perfect world the phone company would provide a web service to make the same info available (with all the authentication/authorization stuff), but not in the real world (at least not when the end user is a single consumer). I would like to have an automated task on my pc (or whatever device) that would do that for me...

Comment: What I need seems more like to a "Web Scraper", like HtmlUnit...